Running range receptacle cable through rim joist and floor sill?
I'm looking for suggestions on how to best run the cable for my range receptacle.
This diagram shows some of the construction involved:

This is a section of my exterior wall.  My house has no sill plate, and the rim joists rest directly on the foundation.  There may be some gap between the two rim joists, also.
I've added a sistered joist to level the floor, which faces the inside of the kitchen.  The new subfloor will rest on this sistered joist.  The other floor joists are parallel to this joist.
There are some old holes where the old cables were run diagonally through the sill, and through the inner rim joist.  However, these holes are now covered by the new joist, and none of them were the right diameter for a #6 or #8 cable.
I have to run the cable upwards in roughly this location, as there are some new load-bearing posts about 3' either side of the target stud bay, and I do not want to drill through these (otherwise I could go up through an interior wall).
Is my best bet to drill downwards through the sill, and perhaps at a 45 degree angle through the sistered joist, creating a 45 degree turn?  I've read that some people instead notch the sill the depth of the cable and use a protective plate, but I think the thickness of the cable will limit how much it can sharply bend.
Thank you for your time and input!

Usually the most elegant solution (since this is in an area you see once every 25 years or so when replacing a range) is to drill a hole straight through the floor, missing all the framing at the corner. If it's more or less in the middle of the range opening (not right on one edge or the other) that won't interfere with most ranges.

Thank you!  I am considering this as well.  Would you then use shielded cable or conduit with a wall mounted box?  Or are there any good floor-mounted options?

Check with your LAHJ as to whether you need to use armored cable or conduit - it's debatable whether it's "exposed to damage" given there's a few hundred pounds of steel range protecting it, but keep them (or yourself) happy on that point. Wall mount for sure IMHO, (potentially in-wall for clearance) because spills and boil-overs are not unusual around ranges; and a floor-mount is just begging for trouble on that point.

Ok - so basically box in the wall as normal, then cable going up through the subfloor and then turning into the stud bay, stapled to stud and into box, and later drywall around the cable?

... after checking with your LAHJ to see if that cable needs to be armored type.
